# MAGMA : Automorphism Groups acting on Involutions

Tags: finite-group-theory

For example if we let

> G:= Sym(6);
>
> A:= AutomorphismGroup(G);
>
> P:= PermutationGroup(A);
>
> I:= {@ i : i in G | Order(i) eq 2 @};

then how does one construct the G-set that has the P acting on I by the map the shows how the automorphisms permute the involutions?

I'm new to MAGMA but I have speant a lot of time reading the handbook lately and I have not found any way to do this. Does anyone have any helpful suggestions?

Comment: The magma you tagged this question with is this: http://icl.utk.edu/magma/ . I think you are asking this question in the wrong place

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out to me. I will try post this in the appropriate place now.